# Wildfly Custom auth-method

Tags: authentication, wildfly

How do you add a custom authenticator in Wildfly?  I used to do this in JBoss 4.2:

In `<JBoss>`\jboss-as\server\production\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\META-INF\jboss-service.xml, add the following in :

```
 <java:property>
      <java:key>MY-CUSTOM-AUTH</java:key>
      <java:value>com.test.MyCustomAuthenticator</java:value>
 </java:property>
```

In `<JBoss>`\jboss-as\server\production\deploy\jboss-portal-ha.sar\portal-server.war\WEB-INF\web.xml, modify :

```
...
 <login-config>
      <auth-method>MY-CUSTOM-AUTH</auth-method>
...
```

Wildfly does not have jboss-service.xml anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer.  We need to create an Undertow ServletExtension (io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension) in the META-INF/services to register the authentication mechanism .  My extension class looks like this:

```
public class NtlmServletExtension implements ServletExtension {
    @Override
    public void handleDeployment(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo, ServletContext servletContext) {
        deploymentInfo.addAuthenticationMechanism("NTLM", new NtlmAuthenticationMechanism.Factory());
    }
}
```

Check this for more details:  http://undertow.io/documentation/servlet/security.html

Here's a sample:
https://github.com/dstraub/spnego-wildfly

You can now refer to this in your web.xml:

```
...
 <login-config>
      <auth-method>NTLM</auth-method>
...
```

Comment: Do you have any implementation ready for NTLM? I'm using waffle right now, but the created principle is not available in an injected `HttpServletRequest`. That's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: hi, i try to to use NTLM in wildlfy , but i block on use what librairie to retrieve the NTLM because before we used waffle but based on valve and tomcat class, jcifs is useless do you have the code of NTLMMechanism please ?

Answer (score 0):

In WildFly you have to use a security realm for that :

- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+Realms for reference.
- http://www.radcortez.com/custom-principal-and-loginmodule-for-wildfly/ as an example

Comment: Custom Authentication method is something different than custom Login module ;)