# Wildfly custom login module never gets executed?

Tags: java, wildfly, jaas

I have created a custom login module for my web application running in Wildfly 8.0.  Here is the module:

```
package bmacs.auth;

import java.security.acl.Group;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup;
import org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal;
import org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule;

public class BasicLoginModule extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule
{
    @Override
    protected String getUsersPassword() throws LoginException
    {
        System.out.println("custom getUsersPassword");
        System.out.format("MyLoginModule: authenticating user '%s'\n",
                getUsername());
        String password = super.getUsername();
        password = password.toUpperCase();
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword,
            String expectedPassword)
    {
        System.out.println("custom validatePassword");
        String encryptedInputPassword = (inputPassword == null) ? null
                : inputPassword.toUpperCase();
        System.out.format(
                "Validating that (encrypted) input psw '%s' equals to (encrypted) '%s'\n"
                , encryptedInputPassword, expectedPassword);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException
    {
        System.out.println("custom getRoleSets");
        SimpleGroup group = new SimpleGroup("Roles");
        try {
            System.out.println("Search here group for user: "+super.getUsername());
            group.addMember(new SimplePrincipal("RoleReportEnrollmentViewer"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new LoginException("Failed to create group member for " + group);
        }
        return new Group[] { group };
    }
}
```

Here is my new security domain I added to standalone.xml

```
<security-domain name="simple-auth" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="bmacs.auth.BasicLoginModule" flag="required" module="login"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

Here is my web app's jboss-web.xml, which references the security domain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">simple-auth</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

When I try to login (through form authentication J_SECURITY_CHECK), it does nothing.  The only thing that shows up in the log is these 2 lines, which isn't much help

```
16:55:09,622 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-9) PBOX000200: Begin isValid, principal: org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.AccountImpl$AccountPrincipal@c9c352bc, cache entry: null
16:55:09,625 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-9) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

What am I missing?  The System.out.println statements in the custom login never print anything/not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Check again the jboss-web.xml. I think that you have to setting
the security roles in the xml. 
I give you a url that may help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726261/form-based-authentication-in-wildfly-with-jsf

Tell me something if it works for you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue like that recently. Look at this WildFly bug created by me where you can find a workaround: [WFLY-4761](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4761). Contact me if you need more help after reading the link.

Edit: As a reaction to comment of [Newd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836853/newd) I am adding little more description. There is a bug in WildFly 8.2.0 where unchecked exceptions in login modules are eaten. The workaround is patching picketbox-infinispan-4.0.21.Final.jar by modified class org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager where runtime errors in the second part of implementation of defaultLogin method are caught and rethrown wrapped by LoginException. The original question was related to WildFly 8.0 where you have to do the same with older version picketbox-infinispan-4.0.20.Final.jar. Please note that the problem can be also caused by unsatisfied module dependencies (WildFly modules have to have their dependencies declared explicitly).

Once you patch the library, errors in your module start appearing in WildFly log file.

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, an answer should be enhanced by a link not dependent on it.  If that link ever goes down your answer will become completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a new authentication mechanism :

[Wildfly Custom auth-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416668/wildfly-custom-auth-method)

you have to create a new class implements wildfly interface and in web.xml login config uses your new configuration ... you can also check in the imported sources class from wildfly : FormAuthenticationMecanism explanations form wildfly 9 but it is the same in wildfly 8